# fatal: $HOME not set on POP OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

I am on POP OS which is based on ubuntu. trying to git commit but getting `fatal: $HOME not set`.
I tried `git config --global user.email "my email"` but not setting the config. also tried with `sudo` still same error. i could not find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the content of $HOME

```
echo $HOME
```

if its empty you can just set it to your home directory by doing

> For fish shell

```
set $HOME =  /home/{_user_name_}
```

Comment: thank you . after running this on bash echo $HOME still returns empty

Comment: Hi Aurora, on bash you would have to do something like : 
export $HOME =  /home/{_user_name_}